# "Cannot find symbol " for All stock android imports/classes

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-build

I ran a ./gradlew assembleDebug but `compileDebugJavaWithJavac` task failed on many errors, I checked most of the errors, they're stock android classes like `android.net.NetworkPolicy`, `android.net.EthernetManager` and `IpConfiguration`, I checked SDK Manager and I did have the targeted sdk installed, and same version of gradle. Never ran into this before, anyone has some insight to this?

Thanks!!

Comment: Try running `gradle clean` or better delete the `gradle` folder and start fresh.

Comment: Also, If you are using android studio, `invalidate caches and restart`.